# Casting Parameterized type class argument into sub-class form when extracting the value of the Parameterized Type

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, casting, parameterized-types

How can I cast the Parameterized type class argument into its sub-class form?
I've read a lot of examples and problems regarding with **extracting the value of the type parameter**, that you should have an interface or abstract class where you should **extend** from.

Consider the codes below

```
type = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType)(getClass().getGenericSuperclass())).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

using the above code, you can cast the "type" variable into something what (Class<T>) represents. Assuming <T> is a **Person.class**

Below is the complete implementation, where Person class is the value being passed into the generic super class type parameter argument. When I create an instance of the generic subclass and **I pass a subclass of Person type parameter argument**, its always being casted into a Person. the **type == Student.class** prints **false** or even if I print the type, its always printing **Person** instead of **Student**. How can i achieve this? is the thing that I want even possible?

**Generic Sub class**

```
public class GenericSubClass<T extends Person> extends GenericAbstractSuper<Person> {

public Class<T> type;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public GenericSubClass() {

    type = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) (getClass().getGenericSuperclass())).getActualTypeArguments()[0];

    System.out.println(type.getSimpleName());
    System.out.println(type == Student.class);
} 

public static void main(String[] args) {

    GenericSubClass<Student> genStud = new GenericSubClass<Student>();
 // GenericSubClass<Employee> genEmp = new GenericSubClass<Employee>();
 // GenericSubClass<Person> genPer = new GenericSubClass<Person>();
  }
}
```

**Generic Super Abstract class**

```
public abstract class GenericAbstractSuper<T> {
}
```

Please I really need some help. I cant find a similar issue around.

Comment: One question: what exactly are you trying to get here? And why are you doing this? As for your issue, you cannot get the type parameter at runtime. With the reflection thing, what you get is the declared type parameter, i.e., `Person`, because you are extending from `GenericAbstractSuper<Person>`. Moreover, that method will fail if your super class is not generic.

Comment: What @Rohit Jain said.  Moreover, a large part of the point of using generics is that you don't *need* to cast if you use them effectively.  I think you need to take a step back and look at the bigger picture of your current design.

Comment: thanks for the responses, actually I'm creating a Specific Utility class that will do something for a Person and its sub-classes(Students etc), but I can only access the properties of Person with this kind of design(e.g access the properties of sub-classes of the type parameter Person), so I'm trying to investigate if I can do it with this kind of approach, the actual name of the Utility class is "EntityPropertiesValidator<Person>" you can already  guess what this class might do for Person and its subclasses ("EntityPropertiesValidator<Student>"

Comment: some methods that will deal to the properties of any Class that extends Person. I was actually thinking of just passing a class type into the class's constructor, "EntityPropertiesValidator ent = new EntitPropertiesValidator(Student.class)", I was inspired by how Colletion frameworks are designed like for example, List<SomeClass> that can deal with anything I pass into it.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to create a subclass of your `GenericSubClass`, anonymous or otherwise.

```
GenericSubClass<Student> genStud = new GenericSubClass<Student>(){};
```

Now

```
getClass().getGenericSuperclass()
```

will return a `Type` for `GenericSubClass<Student>` and you can extract `Student`.

Previously,

```
getClass().getGenericSuperclass()
```

was returning `GenericAbstractSuper<Person>` so you were extracting `Person`.

This trick is used in **type tokens**.

Comment: oh yes type tokens, I even encountered Neil Gafter's Super Type tokens, but it really looks peculiar to me, but I tried it and its good, I can construct different types using his approach, [link](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) , I was just hoping if I can achieve what I want with my design and similar resources, utilizing every thing that I can find., I'm gonna try your code, and I will thank you in advance. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Jeff There is a sophisticated implementation of type tokens in Google Guava: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReflectionExplained

Comment: @Marco13 thanks a lot, so that's just the simple word I need to take another step "type tokens", I'm just stuck up having some trouble thinking of a word or segment where I can continue digging into generics. Thank you